# API for my Azure Function App gives me error code 500

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-function-app-proxy, azure-functions-core-tools

I'm trying to use [this Azure Function App python library](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-docker-python-sample), and following the small Hello World tutorial in the readme.

The push to Docker hub works fine, the function is created and appears in Portal, and I can access the main URL in my browser (*Your Functions 2.0 app is up and running*).

Everything seems fine until I try to call the API with the http:

```
http://funcmandag.azurewebsites.net/api/HttpTriggerJS1?name=NorwegianClassic
```

It returns http error code 500. This also happens locally. In Portal the function blade of the Function app in Function Apps says: *Read-Only*. What does this mean?

Has anyone a suggestion? How can I debug this?

Comment: Regarding the Read-only you can [refer here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-ux/issues/1712#issuecomment-343289512) to solve it

Comment: Really appreciated @Jayendran, thank you! It says: _This feature is not supported for Linux apps._ Do you know if this matter? This is a JSON generated function. For now I have no plans on adding extra functions to my Function App.

Comment: Just try with `Advance Tools (Kudu)` then using bash go to the directory `home/site/wwwroot/<your function>` then delete the "generatedBy" property in your function.json(s).

Comment: Its nothing there! What does this mean? Can this be the root of all my problems?

Comment: Basically, I'm trying to solve the issue to fix the `Function Apps says: Read-Only` this can be done using deleting the `generateBy` Property in your `functions.json`
[In this image](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/645740/32629357-cd5d8044-c54d-11e7-85ec-f5d06baad758.png) above the App service Editory there is a option called `Advance Tools (kudu)` which helps you to view your function app throguh cmdlets

Comment: Yeah, I know. And I used Kudu to check the wwwroot folder, it was empty.

Comment: Is this question about it being read-only in the portal (which is by design), or about the 500? All the discussions seem to be about the read-only. Also, if you say you can repro locally, I highly suggest focusing on that and leave Azure out of the picture. In other words, please simply/clarify your question so it focuses on the essential.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issues, the solutions are written here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-docker-python-sample/issues/19